# ¿Cómo asignar valor de un campo input a un array?

Tags: javascript, array, entrada

Estoy haciendo un programa en `JavaScript` en el que el usuario ingrese un número (siempre debe ser impar y mayor que 13, el usuario podrá ingresar tantos números como quiera.

he hecho esto:

```js
var vector = new Array();
var numeros = 0;
var contador = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
      document.write("El numero del medio es: " + contador + "<br>" + "De menor a mayor:" + numeros )
```

```html
<p> El numero debe ser impar y mayor a 5 </p>
<input type="number" name="formulario">
<button id="mostrar">Mostrar</button>
<button id="Siguiente">Siguiente</button>
```

Mi idea es crear un campo con 2 botones, uno en que el usuario vaya agregando todos los números que quiera y presionando siguiente hasta terminar y el que al oprimir el botón mostrar muestre el número medio del `array` y los ordene de  menor a mayor.

Mi pregunta es : ¿Cómo hago para asignar los valores introducidos por el usuario a un array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar dejar claro que es una mala practica emplear `document.write` en su lugar puede tener algún otro elemento para mostrar los resultados *(un div por ejemplo)* donde mostraremos los mensajes correspondientes al procedimiento realizado o errores si es que los hubiera.

Luego su código tiene errore de sintaxis , el cierre de las llaves del `for`

> ¿Cómo hago para asignar los valores introducidos por el usuario a un
>   array?

Existe varias formas de añadir un elemento a un `array` para este ejemplo se usará [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)  , el código está comentado

```js
var array = [];
var btnsiguiente = document.getElementById('siguiente');
var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
var btnmostrar = document.getElementById('mostrar');

btnsiguiente.addEventListener('click',function(){
    var  text = document.getElementById('valor').value;
    /* Verificamos que el campo no esté vacío */
    if(text.length>0){
        valor = parseInt(text);
        /* Verificamos que el valor sea par y mayor a 13*/
        if(valor%2===0 && valor>13){
            resultado.innerText= 'Número ingresado correctamente';
            /* Añadimos el valor al Array */
            array.push(valor);
        }
        else
            resultado.innerText = "Número debe ser Par y mayor a 13";
    }
    else resultado.innerText = "Campo Número vacío"; 
});



btnmostrar.addEventListener('click',function(){
    /* Ordenamos el Array con sort*/
    if(array.length!==0){
        array.sort((i,j)=>  i-j);
        resultado.innerText='';
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            resultado.innerText +=array[i] + " - " ;
        }
        resultado.innerText +="\n" + "Valor Intermedio : " + array[parseInt(array.length/2)];
    }
    else resultado.innerText = "No hay números ingresados";
    
});
```

```html
<p> El numero debe ser impar y mayor a 5 </p>
<input type="number" name="formulario" id="valor">
<button id="mostrar">Mostrar</button>
<button id="siguiente">Siguiente</button>
<div id="resultado">
    
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda.
Una pregunta: veo que en el código has puesto para los números pares 
o sea valor%2===0 si no me equivoco eso me daría resto 0 es decir no me daría el numero medio del array,  entonces tendría que contar los valores del array para conocer la longitud con .length y recién ahí hallar el numero del medio ¿es correcto?

Comment: Esa es solo la verificación para saber si es par o no. Para saber la cantidad de elementos se usa `length` como en la segunda parte del código. Y para el valor medio este `length` lo divido entre 2

Comment: @condor12 recuerde que si mi respuesta le resolvió su problema marcarla como aceptada. Así evitamos preguntas abiertas.  Saludos